# How can I pass result generated from mysql query on other page

Tags: php

file1.php

```
<form action="file2.php" name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<table>
<tr>
  <td><img src="photos/"<?php echo $picture1_name."";?> alt="iage"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['user_id'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];

include 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE firstname='$firstname'";
$rows = $conn-> query($sql);
   if ($rows->num_rows > 0) {
   $rows=$rows->fetch_assoc();
   $data['id'] = $rows['id'];
   $data['user_id'] = $rows['user_id'];
   $data['picture1_name'] = $rows['picture1_name'];
}else {
    echo "No record found.";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

I want to show result coming from file2.php on file1.php in table inside input fields values, but its not coming and control stays on file2.php.
How can i do this, it gives me error on file1.php: undefined $picture1_name & $firstname. Please guide me somebody

Comment: always use `isset()` or `!empty()` on variables, or a ternary operator. That's why you're getting those warnings; they're not "defined" in your first file. You're kind of like putting the wagon before the horse, as it were ;-)

Comment: but, how to get the data on file1.php in value=""?